# A Monster Who Is Also A Savior

Tags: riddle, poetry

I am dead and lifeless
I am a monster, cold
Look at me a closer look
Gasp and behold!

Older than your pyramids
And far more than your Rome
I am older than it all
As old as your home

If it were not me, you know
They'd stone you soon to death
Giant boulders would crush you
And take your last breath

If I came alone for you
And you come, you four
I'd be left standing and
You all would be no more

I am father of them all
Who wander in the sky
And whoever wanders close
Must invariably die

**HINTS**

The hints are right there in all the stanzas. But still, let me put them simply in non-poetic form:

Stanza1

> I am a giant *dead* monster. If you look at me in detail, you would be horrified.

Stanza2

> I am far older than Rome or the Egyptian pyramids. I am almost as old as your home is.

Stanza3

> If it was not for my presence, *they* would stone you to your death. Giant rocks would fall on you and leave no-one alive!

Stanza4

> If you gather your 3 partners and try to come for a battle with me, it would be me who would be left while all of you would be obliterated.

Stanza5

> I am the father of the vagabonds. If anyone comes too close to me, death is certain for him!

Comment: Negative rep without a comment is so cool!

Comment: There is [a discussion about this question](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4592/should-questions-needing-no-clear-answers-be-allowed) on meta.

Comment: Thanks eff for the update. I have edited it to remove the controversial part.

Comment: Please don't post the answer after a day... wait at least a week or two!

Comment: The only reason I might post the answer before this is that the fellow members appear to hate this question. The longer it stands, the more negative rep it will muster.

Comment: I've removed the downvote now that you've taken out the request not to post the answer. (I recommend posting hints rather than an answer, by the way - it gives people more time to think about it. Not all puzzles are solved quickly - [this one](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16881/lepidopterology-needed) took five months!)

Comment: Be patient. If your puzzle is good, it will eventually be solved. I would recommend posting "hints" only if long periods of time have passed with nobody posting anything... You don't want to spoil your own puzzle by being too impatient and giving it away too soon.

Comment: OK then. * breathes deeply and sits in yoga pose *. My vigil begins now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it ...

> ... Jupiter?

I am dead and lifeless
I am a monster, cold

> Well nothing lives on Jupiter, and it is -108°C

Look at me a closer look
Gasp and behold!

> Feel the menace of the EYE OF JUPITER!!!!

Older than your pyramids
And far more than your Rome
I am older than it all
As old as your home

> (very) roughly as old as all planets in the solar system, like Earth, our home.

If it were not me, you know
They'd stone you soon to death
Giant boulders would crush you
And take your last breath

> Vacuums up asteroids before they can hit any of the inner planets

If I came alone for you
And you come, you four
I'd be left standing and
You all would be no more

> A lot heavier than all the four inner planets (and maybe the outer planets, dunno) combined.

I am father of them all
Who wander in the sky

> The Romans shamelessly stole and renamed the population of the Greek pantheon, and thereby their names for the planets (Greek for wanderers). Zeus the father of gods, became Jupiter.

And whoever wanders close
Must invariably die

> ... or wait until Elon Musk sells Eye-Diving Tickets to billionaires and opens a wellness spa on the ground below...

Comment: ... and here was, thinking it would take weeks for someone to correctly understand ***everything*** hinted in the riddle! There are indeed smarter people in the world than I think there are.

Comment: Btw the "gasp and behold" part wasn't for the _eye_ of Jupiter. It was the awe you feel when you learn it is the size of more than 100 earths ... "And whoever wanders close ... Must invariably die" I would reckon falling into Jupiter would be one of the most horrific deaths conceivable for a human mind.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

> the moon

"I am dead and lifeless
I am a monster, cold
Look at me a closer look
Gasp and behold!"

> It doesn't have life in it, or life itself, and is cold and big.

"Older than your pyramids
And far more than your Rome
I am older than it all
As old as your home"

> It was created when the earth was created, which is "our home" and far older than any of our civilizations.

"If it were not me, you know
They'd stone you soon to death
Giant boulders would crush you
And take your last breath"

> All the Craters of the moon exist there by a reason, and is because it doesn't have any atmosfere, but also has been a shield for earth from many generations and Eons.

"If I came alone for you
And you come, you four
I'd be left standing and
You all would be no more"

> Like astronauts?, without atmosphere, there is no chance to survive, plus the effect on the sea would affect the life on earth considerably, so we'll "die" if we lose it.

"I am father of them all
Who wander in the sky
And whoever wanders close
Must invariably die"

> No Atmosphere point all over again.

Comment: Very nice reasoning user! I'm quite surprised with your attempt. Will announce the answer after 24 hours (unless asked to delay).

Comment: @YoustayIgo You should *not* answer your own question, unless you have a very good reason to. You should *accept* a correct answer, if you find it satisfying (and usually at once), or you should *wait* until one is found. Only if you find your own puzzle "lacking" you should "improve" it by edits (and maybe hints), but do so sparingly!

Comment: OK. Waiting for further answers then :p  Btw user has reasoned impressively ^_^